# Setting 'badge' to 'panel' in framework ui `ant design`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Is it possible to set `Badge` to `Panel` next to 'Info' in `ant design`?

[image]

[Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tdfe7y)

```js
<div>
  <Collapse>
    <Panel header="Info" key="1">
      <Badge
        count={4}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          color: "#999",
          boxShadow: "0 0 0 1px #d9d9d9 inset"
        }}
      />
    </Panel>
  </Collapse>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`Collapse.Panel`](https://ant.design/components/collapse/#Collapse.Panel) -  `header` prop accepts `ReactNode` so you can render whatever you want, for [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-antd-react-starter-x6xx0), using antd `Grid`:

[image]

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Collapse>
      <Collapse.Panel
        header={
          <Row type="flex" gutter={10}>
            <Col>Info</Col>
            <Col>
              <Badge
                count={4}
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: '#fff',
                  color: '#999',
                  boxShadow: '0 0 0 1px #d9d9d9 inset'
                }}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        }
        key="1"
      />
    </Collapse>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit styled-antd-react-starter]

Comment: '4' I have at the bottom. How can I center this '4'? Drawing: https://imgur.com/pSlryx1

Comment: I dont know how the parent is styled, please just post another question and accept current answer if it was helpful

Comment: Should I create a new question?